# Regex to remove punctuation and characters

Tags: regex, lambda

I have a List and wish to clean it up by removing various characters. I decided to try Lambda and Regex for the first time but have fallen flat on my face.

```
foreach (var str in listResults)
    {
       listResults.Select(c => {c = removePunctuation(c); return c;}).ToList(); 
    }


private string removePunctuation(string str)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(str, @"\t|\n|\r|.|,|:|;|!", " ");
    }
```

Comment: not the issue, but `listResults.Select(c => {c = removePunctuation(c); return c;}).ToList(); ` => `listResults.Select(c => removePunctuation(c)).ToList();`, and remove the `foreach` ! The whole expression returns a list of the transformed values.

Comment: `.` matches any char, you need to use `\.` to match a dot. You should actually use a character class for punctuation, `\p{P}` - `return Regex.Replace(str, @"\p{P}", " ");`. Or, if you also want to match symbols, `Regex.Replace(str, @"[\p{S}\p{P}]", " ")`. If you need to shrink 1+ consecutive punctuation chars with a single space, use `+` after the character class, `Regex.Replace(str, @"[\p{S}\p{P}]+", " ")`